# Nesting SQL queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have the following SQL query. In this query, I am left joining a table tblTestImport with access query named "unique". I am trying to integrate the query "unique" into the code below. I am not having any luck, please help.

```
DELETE tblTestImport.ID
FROM tblTestImport
WHERE tblTestImport.[ID]

in (SELECT tblTestImport.ID
FROM tblTestImport 
LEFT JOIN **[unique]**

ON tblTestImport.ID = **unique.**LastOfID

WHERE (((**unique.**LastOfID) Is Null)));
```

Code for "unique" query

```
SELECT Last(tblTestImport.ID) AS LastOfID
FROM tblTestImport
GROUP BY tblTestImport.Url, tblTestImport.Kms, tblTestImport.Price, tblTestImport.Time;
```

Further info: I am trying to delete duplicates from the Access Table, and leave unique ones only.
tblTestImport has duplicate records. "Unique" query displays unique records. Then, I join tblTestImport table with "unique" query, to determine which unique records do not exist in tblTestImport. This gives me a list duplicates, which I want to delete.

Within the big chunk of code, i have [unique], which I would like replace with small piece of code below.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: edited to include more detail. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your query will return no results, assuming that `id` is never `NULL`.

Why?  Well `unique.lastOfId` is always a valid id in `tblTestImport`.  As such, the `LEFT JOIN` will always match, and `lastOfId` will never be `NULL`.

So, no rows are in the subquery.

My suggestion is that you ask another question.  Explain what you want to do and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're after based on the current setup of your question. However, this may be what you're looking for:

```
DELETE tblTestImport.ID
FROM tblTestImport
WHERE tblTestImport.[ID] IN
    (SELECT tblTestImport.ID
    FROM tblTestImport 
    LEFT JOIN [unique] ON tblTestImport.ID = unique.LastOfID
    WHERE unique.LastOfID Is Null
    AND tblTestImport.ID IN (
        SELECT Last(tblTestImport.ID) AS LastOfID
        FROM tblTestImport
        GROUP BY tblTestImport.Url, tblTestImport.Kms, tblTestImport.Price, tblTestImport.Time)
    )
```

(This is a simple nested query in the previous query, but it would all depend on the relationship of the data itself. This query assumes that they are linked on the same tblTestImport.ID field)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, untested:

```
DELETE FROM tblTestImport
WHERE ID <>  (SELECT Min(ID) AS MinOfID FROM tblTestImport AS Dupe      
   WHERE (Dupe.Url= tblTestImport.Url)                         
   AND (Dupe.Kms= tblTestImport.Kms)
   AND (Dupe.Price= tblTestImport.Price)
   AND (Dupe.Time= tblTestImport.Time));
```

Solution based on the following http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html